# Does a relay write to disk frequently?

Tags: relays, raspberry-pi

I'm a new relay operator. I'm running a non-exit relay on a Raspberry Pi, whose main storage device is an SD card. I'm concerned that the relay software may be shortening the life of my SD card by writing frequently. Can anyone help me understand how much writing to disk the relay software does? Is it all in memory?

I can't seem to find this info on Google. I found a similar question on this forum without answer, and it was marked duplicate but didn't lead to another thread. I apologize if I've duplicated in my ignorance.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may be interested in looking to set the [`AvoidDiskWrites`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#AvoidDiskWrites) option in your torrc.

Answer (score 2):

Tor usually writes data into the [`DataDirectory`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#DataDirectory). This includes information about the network, status information about your relay and other information. Those files are regularly updated.

You can move the `DataDirectory` to some directory outside of your SD card if possible. Another way is to set `AvoidDiskWrites 1` in your `torrc`. If set Tor will try to write less frequently to disk.

Comment: One more thing to add - I'm running a relay on a OrangePi - use a tmpfs benefits and make a fine-grained sync in both sides. I'll publish my solution for this soon(I hope). It's not just elongating a flash-memory life, but it's also a fuckup-proof: even if a person will steal your relat physically, you can be sure, that no data is leaked out actually